# TicTacToe Array. Winner method and is square free

Tags: arrays, tic-tac-toe

I dont know what I'm doing wrong here. 
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my `checkRow` code in `checkWinner` and `isSquareFree` method?

Here's my code:

```
public class TicTacToe
{
/**
* intance variables to hold the data's state for the game.
*/
    public static final int GRIDSIZE = 3;
    public static final char BLANK = ' ';
    public static final char TIE = 'T';
    public static final char NOUGHT = 'O';
    public static final char CROSS = 'X';

    private char[][] grid;
    private char WhoseTurn;

    /**
     * Construct a tic tac toe grid ready to play a new game.
     * The game grid should be GRIDSIZE by GRIDSIZE spaces
     * all containing the BLANK character.
     * Initially, the starting player is not decided,
     * indicated by setting whoseturn as BLANK.
     */
    public TicTacToe()
    {

       this.WhoseTurn = BLANK;
       this.grid = new char[GRIDSIZE][GRIDSIZE];
      for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) 
        {
            for ( int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++)
            {
            this.grid[r][c] = BLANK;
        }

    }
}
   /**
* Reset the tic tac toe game ready to play again.
* Conditions for play are the same as for the constructor.
*/
public void newGame()
{  
   char[][] boardToClear = getGrid();
   final int sizeOfBoard = grid.length;
   for ( int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++)
   {
       for ( int col = 0; col < grid.length; col++)
       {
           grid[row][col] = BLANK;
        }
    }
}
 public char[][] getGrid()
 {
    int gridLen = grid.length;
    char[][] gridCopy = new char[gridLen][];
    for ( int r = 0; r < gridCopy.length; r++)
    {
        gridCopy[r] = new char[gridCopy.length];
        for ( int c = 0; c < gridCopy.length; c++)
        {
            gridCopy[r][c] = grid[r][c];
        }
    }
return gridCopy;
}

    public char getWhoseTurn()
    {
        return WhoseTurn;
    }

/**
* printGrid() displays the current state of the game grid 
* on the console for debugging.
* It uses the form feed character \u000C to clear the console before
* printing the current grid.
*/

    private void printGrid() 
      {
        System.out.print('\u000C'); // clear the console window
        for (int x = 0; x < GRIDSIZE-1; x++) { 
            System.out.print(grid[x][0] + "|" +
                       grid[x][1] + "|" + grid[x][2]);
            System.out.println("\n-----"); //
            System.out.print(grid[GRIDSIZE-1][0] + "|" + 
            grid[GRIDSIZE-1][1] + "|" + 
            grid[GRIDSIZE-1][2]);
    }
        }
        // Now print last row (with no bottom edge)

        private boolean checkIfGridFull()
        {
            char[][] board = getGrid();
            int size = grid.length;
            for ( int row = 0; row < size; row++)
            {
                for ( int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++)
                {
                    if ( grid[row][col] == BLANK)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }




        public boolean move(char player, int row, int col)
        {


          char[][] boardToPlay = getGrid();
            int size = grid.length;
            char x = player;

         if ( (player == NOUGHT) || ( player == CROSS))
           {
                if ( (x == WhoseTurn) || (WhoseTurn == BLANK))
               {
                   if ((checkIfGridFull() == false) && ( boardToPlay[row][col] == BLANK))
                   {

                       if( (row < size) && ( col < size))
                       {

                      boardToPlay[row][col] = player;
                      if ( player == CROSS)
            {
                WhoseTurn = NOUGHT;
            }
            if ( player == NOUGHT)
            {
                WhoseTurn = CROSS;
            }

                       return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }





        return false;
    }
    public boolean isSquareFree( int row, int col)
        {


            if ((grid[row][col] == BLANK))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false
            ;
        }

        public char checkWinner()
        {
            int countNought;
            int countCross ;
            int size = grid.length;

            for ( int row = 0; row < size; row++)
            {
                countNought = 0;
                countCross = 0;

                for ( int col = 0; col < size; col++)
                {
                    if ( grid[row][col] == CROSS)
                    {
                        countCross++;
                    }
                    if ( grid[row][col] == NOUGHT)
                    {
                        countNought++;
                    }
                    if ( countNought == size)
                    {
                        return NOUGHT;
                    }
                    if ( countCross == size)
                    {
                        return CROSS;
                    }
                }
            }

            return BLANK;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One good method for tracking down a bug in a project like this is to use print line statements. Try this: put a print line somewhere near where you think the problem is, and print out the values of some of the local variables. If you see values that you shouldn't then you know that your data has come into some trouble earlier on in the code. In that case, move the print lines further back in the flow and try again. Keep doing this until you notice values going from good to bad (or bad to good): at that point you have tracked down the code that contains the bug.

Once you've done this, you will usually have only a small function to think about, and it will be much easier to understand what you've done wrong. If you still can't find the problem, then post the code snippet here and someone will probably be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

checkWinner() is wrong you're not checking diagonals, just write the eights winning combinations